# How to build using cra-append-sw now that @babel/polyfill has been deprecated?

Tags: service-worker, create-react-app, babel-polyfill

I'm trying to add functionality to the serviceworker that create-react-app provides out of the box. Thankfully, cra-append-sw lets me do that without needing to eject from cra.

However, when installing cra-append-sw, npm gives me a warning that @babel/polyfill@7.4.4 has been deprecated (@babel/polyfill is listed as a cra-append-sw dependency):

```
As of Babel 7.4.0, this package has been deprecated in favor of directly including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime (needed to use transpiled generator functions):

import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```

Then, when I try to `npm run build` to append a custom service worker, the build spits out a long error message, the top of which is:

```
ERROR in multi ./custom-sw.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './custom-sw.js' in '/Users/michaelmersiades/workspace/vanilla-cra'
resolve './custom-sw.js' in '/Users/--/workspace/vanilla-cra'
  using description file: /Users/--/workspace/vanilla-cra/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

and custom-sw.js is not showing up in the build folder.

Is this fixable? If so, how? Or is this an issue for the good ira-append-sw folk?

My thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Silly error. The custom-sw.js file was inside /src, but it needed to be in / (the root folder).

Moving it to / solved the problem.